# AngularJs Material design RTL layout

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

how can I change the whole layout of the angularjs material design component to RTL ?

Comment: What is RTL? Some more details for your question will help.

Comment: I mean Right to Left layout. For some languages line Persian or Arabic.

Answer (score 8):

you can do this by BiDirectional Provider

```
app.config(function($mdBiDirectionalProvider) {
    $mdBiDirectionalProvider.rtlMode(true);
}
```

look at this [page](https://github.com/angular/material/pull/1711#partial-pull-merging)

Comment: Oh, didn't know we had a config for that! ;-)

Comment: Great! but where does mdBiDirectionalProvider gets refrenced? does it work without implementation?

Comment: seems it didn't merged yet to the main branch. you can clone related tree (https://github.com/angular/material/tree/08bf4f93763d2aea9901d697f8cc3786d242725f) and build it yourself. although using ```$mdBiDirectionalProvider``` is not necessary. just by inserting ```dir="rtl"``` in the body works for me successfully.

Comment: @Mehdi: What is recommended way to change Angular-Material components' direction to rtl right now? Why there is no document for it? Currently i tried angular-material for a small project but I got despondent... Do you recommend MD?

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple way to change page layout.

**<*html dir="rtl"*>**

just this

Comment: yes you can do this, but some components and features like tabs transition dose not work correctly in this way

Comment: I agree with @MehdiEmrani, I think that is not the correct way but will work, even Bootstrap has a different version for right to left languages (RTL)

Comment: No, changing the direction to `rtl` will cause the HTML layout to be `rtl` but the materials will remain in `ltr`

Answer (score -2):

Dose not difference between them. Both do the same.

```
function rtlMode(mode) {
    if (mode) {
      direction = 'rtl';
    }
}
```